# WPF Move focus two times to the right

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF TexBox and I would like to move focus two controls to the right on right arrow key.
To move focus one element to the right I use:

```
this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

But to move it two times I cannot find a solution.

Thanks,
Kos

Answer (score 2):

Why move twice? Isn't this just a sign that your tab order is wrong?

I'd fix the tab order. That way the tab key and right arrow key behave similarly.

Also: as a user I'd expect the right arrow key to move the carret inside the textbox, not away from the textbox. that is plainly confusing.